# Changing Volume "kind"

Tags: macos, catalina

I have a Seagate external drive that shows up as an internal volume when mounted in Disk Utility. The info window shows the "kind" and a volume as well. Is there a way to change this, so it appears as an external drive again?[image]

Comment: How is it connected?

Comment: Please select the Seagate drive itself and take another screenshot. You've selected the 'invisible' MacBook Pro partition, which is not giving us any information about the Seagate drive at all.